# set <T> vs set <T, comparator> (C++ polymorphism)

Tags: c++, stl, set, polymorphism

Why does this code

```
struct ThingComparator
{
    ...
}

static void Blah (set <CString> &things)
{
    ...
}

...

set<CString, ThingComparator>things;
Blah (things);
```

fail to compile with the following error (Visual Studio 2010):

```
error C2664: 'Blah' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::set<_Kty,_Pr>' to 'std::set<_Kty> &'
```

My C++ knowledge is obviously limited, but I expected to hear a trumpet announcing the polymorphism knight on his trusty steed, but instead all I can hear is a horse fart and a sad trombone :-(

Comment: Upvoted for hilarity. :D

Comment: @wilx please don't laugh at newbies stumbling upon type errors.

Comment: @elyse: That was not what I find hilarious. It is the last sentence of the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::set` is declared [as follows](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

Hence `std::set<CString>` really means `std::set<CString, std::less<CString>, std::allocator<CString>>`, and `std::less<CString>` isn't `ThingComparator`. Write the following instead:

```
struct ThingComparator {
    ...
};

template<typename Comparator>
static void Blah(std::set<CString, Comparator>& things) {
    ...
}

...

std::set<CString, ThingComparator> things;
Blah(things);
```

Answer (score 1):

The polymorphism involved is not runtime polymorphism, which would be required in your case. The function should be made a template or `std::set<CString, std::function<bool(const CString&, const CString&)>>` to explicitly invoke runtime polymorphism on the comparator.